# popUpButton is setEnabled:YES but doesn't allow click

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nspopupbutton

my popUpButton is in a window with a group of popUpButtons.  If I try to click the 2nd of 4 vertically aligned buttons then the popdown menu will not appear.  If I select the 3rd or 4th then the 2nd will now be selectable.

throughout my code the setEnabled on that popUpButton is :YES.

ideas on where to look in my controller?

This is a Objective C/Cocoa Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was in the -validateMenuItem code... I wasnt checking for a return value of null somewhere that method and it was logically returning false.